# How to send and manipulate an integer in a UDP connection in the terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal, server, udp

So im having trouble with this one portion of my program. Right now with my current code i can connect and communicate with another computer via the terminal but i am unable to send an integer and have it be recognized as such.

I need to be able to send a number to a server, and get the server to manipulate the number (e.g. add 1), and then return the result to client and printout the result on the server side.

I cannot for the life of me get it to recognize this communication as an integer instead of a string!

Here is how i connect in the terminal Server side:

```
python ./udpEchoServer.py -s 4004
```

And here is how i connect in the terminal Client side:

```
python ./udpEchoServer.py -c [IP ADDRESS OF THE SERVER] 4004
```

Here is my code so far:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# Client and server for udp (datagram) echo.
#
# Usage: udpecho -s [port]            (to start a server)
# or:    udpecho -c host [port] <file (client)

import sys
from socket import *

ECHO_PORT = 50000 + 7
BUFSIZE = 1024

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        usage()
    if sys.argv[1] == '-s':
        server()
    elif sys.argv[1] == '-c':
        client()
    else:
        usage()

def usage():
    sys.stdout = sys.stderr
    print 'Usage: udpecho -s [port]            (server)'
    print 'or:    udpecho -c host [port] <file (client)'
    sys.exit(2)

def server():
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        port = eval(sys.argv[2])
    else:
        port = ECHO_PORT
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind(('', port))
    print 'udp echo server ready'
    while 1:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(BUFSIZE)
        print 'server received %r from %r' % (data, addr)
        s.sendto(data, addr)

def client():
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        usage()
    host = sys.argv[2]
    if len(sys.argv) > 3:
        port = eval(sys.argv[3])
    else:
        port = ECHO_PORT
    addr = host, port
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind(('', 0))
    print 'udp echo client ready, reading stdin'
    while 1:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        s.sendto(line, addr)
        data, fromaddr = s.recvfrom(BUFSIZE)
        print 'client received %r from %r' % (data, fromaddr)

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP messages are just bytes. If you want them to pass anything else, you have to *serialize* it on the sending side, and *deserialize* it on the receiving side. (Sometimes this is called marshaling or encoding instead of serializing.)

A common way to serialize data is JSON—it handles smallish ints, floats, strings, lists of dicts of floats, …

But an even simpler way to is to just use `str` and `int`, if all you ever want to send is ints:

```
num = 5
s.sendto(str(num), add)
```

… and to receive a number:

```
data, addr = s.recvfrom(BUFSIZE)
num = int(data)
```

In fact, you're already effectively doing this on the client side—you read a line of input, as a string, and just send it. So you don't need to add anything there, just on the server:

```
data, addr = s.recvfrom(BUFSIZE)
num = int(data)
print 'server received %r from %r' % (data, addr)
data = str(num + 1)
s.sendto(data, addr)
```